# PHP server time convert to left hours count

Tags: php, time

I have a PHP Server time like this [image] and I need to convert this time into  left hours count like this

```
6 hours lefts
7 hours lefts
```

Comment: in the comments to my answer you said you want to calculate the left hours without any other date - but how should that work? you can only get the hours betweens two points in time, when you have two such points. the one seesm to be the current server time, but whats the second? 6 hours left _to what?_

Comment: i'm voting to close this now, because it's impossible to tell whats asked here. safarov and i both explained how to calculate the time-difference between two times and how to convert this to hours - if thats not what you're looking for, you should completely rephrase your question.

Comment: thank for your cooperation but how to initialize server time can you plz guide me  @oezi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$time_left = floor((time() - strtotime($server_time)) / 3600);
echo $time_left.' hours left';
```

Comment: i just follow your instruction but this code has generate a result like this 370234 hours left (i need accurate format like 6 hour) @safarov

Answer (score 1):

1. convert the target-time to a timestamp ([strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), for example)
2. get the current timestamp ([time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php))
3. target - current = seconds left (simple math)
4. convert seconds to hours (math again, using [floor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) on the result)

in code:

```
$target = strtotime($server_time);   // 1 - note: $server_time should be your
                                     //     string, whereever you get that from
$now = time();                       // 2
$left = $target - $now;              // 3
echo floor($left/3600).' hours left';// 4
```

Comment: i just follow your instruction but this code has generate a result like this -370234 hours left (i need accurate format like 6 hour) @oezi

Comment: how was `$server_time` initialized? have you tried outputting interim results? what did these show?

Comment: initialize server time like this $server_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s a"); @oezi

Comment: that defaults to now - so where should the other date come from? please try to provide complete information and don't let us find everything out by asking a thousand questions...

Comment: my Q is how to get lefts hours from server time without any other date